# Get the response data into the jQuery ajaxComplete function

Tags: jquery, ajax

What I would like to do is send the return data from any ajax call and also have it available in the `ajaxComplete` function.

So when I have a `$.post` or `$.get` or `$.getJSON` and so on request like this:

```
$.post(url, options, function(DATA)
{
    $('output').html(DATA);
});
```

I also want to get the same data into:

```
$.ajaxComplete(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions)
{
    // do something with DATA that is returned by the ajax request
    alert(DATA);
});
```

It means I want in the global `ajaxComplete` function also the same data which I get when I call one of the ajax functions.

Answer (score 11):

You can convert to JSON inside your ajaxComplete function by using

```
$.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
```

Answer (score 8):

`XMLHttpRequest.responseText`

Note that if you set the dataType in the call to json or are using the getJSON function  you will have to copy what jquery does internally and use eval( '(' + data + ')' ) to get the data into json so that it mirrors the data param passed to the success callback.

Or as activa points out just call the internal method to save the work.

Comment: jQuery now provides a parseJSON method

Comment: @SpoonMeiser it didnt on July 9th when I posted this!

Comment: No, I didn't mean to suggest it did. It was new in 1.4.1, and 1.3.2 appears to have been current when this question was posed. I just thought it worth making a note.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do that, but you could extract the data from the xhr object. jQuery includes an internal function that does just that, but it's undocumented.

You can call this method like this:

```
$.ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, options)
{
    var data = $.httpData(xhr,options.dataType);

    alert(data);
});
```

But beware: this is valid in jQuery 1.3.2, and because it's undocumented, it can change in future releases of jQuery.

Comment: ++ to call the internal httpData

Comment: As of 1.5 this method has been removed.

Comment: @cletus As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)